# Can I refresh my shell within a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, centos, ruby

I am trying to setup a script that starts with a minimal CentOS 6 install and provisions it for Ruby development.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add PostgreSQL Repo
rpm -i http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5.noarch.rpm

# Add NginX Repo
echo '[nginx]' > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
echo 'name=nginx repo' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
echo 'baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
echo 'gpgcheck=0' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
echo 'enabled=1' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

# Update
yum update -y

# Install NginX, PostgreSQL, and Ruby Dependencies
yum install -y nginx postgresql91-server postgresql91-contrib gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison piconv-devel sqlite-devel git-core

# PostgreSQL Post Install
service postgresql-9.1 initdb
chkconfig postgresql-9.1 on

# Install rbenv system wide install
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /usr/local/rbenv

# Install ruby-build
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

# Add rbenv to the path
echo '# rbenv setup - only add RBENV PATH variables if no single user install found' > /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
echo 'if [[ ! -d "${HOME}/.rbenv" ]]; then' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
echo '  export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
echo '  export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
echo '  eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
echo 'fi'  >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

# SHELL NEEDS TO BE REFRESHED HERE

# Install latest Ruby
rbenv install 1.9.3-p286

# Set Global Ruby
rbenv global 1.9.3-p286
```

I am getting a rbenv: command not found error when it gets to the point where it uses rbenv because my shell needs refreshed/restarted for it to recognize the command.  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try sourcing the new environment files. Looking above, I guess,

```
# SHELL NEEDS TO BE REFRESHED HERE
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
```

and/or

```
source ${HOME}/.rbenv
```

plus any other files that have been created, that you need including in the current shell.

Comment: Thanks.  This did the trick.  In my case only 'source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh' was needed.